# Best way to returns a group by response in spring

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an object that returns me

```
[
  {
    id: 123
    name: 'foo'
    date: 2019-09-08
  },
  {
    id: 124
    name: 'foo2'
    date: 2019-09-08
  },
  {
    id: 125
    name: 'foo3'
    date: 2019-09-09
  },
  {
    id: 126
    name: 'foo4'
    date: 2019-09-09
  }
]
```

Which is the best way to configure an endpoint that gives me these objects grouped by date using Spring Boot?

How can I set a good endpoint name for this feature?

I'm thinking about something like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/somethings")
public List<Something> getSomethings(@RequestParam(value = "groupBy", required = false) String groupBy)
```

Is it a good approach?

Comment: Can you please post expected output?

Comment: Response should have status, messages (if any) and data. You may want to create a domain class called Response which will have all these things. So all your endpoint may return Response object.

Comment: To set a good name you may want to visit https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

Answer (score 0):

Returning the grouped information in a list would not work. You can use a Map with key as the field that you are using to group the list by and value as a list that belongs to that particular group.

For e.g:

```
Map<Date,List<SomeThing>>
```

Hope this helps